How to represent the region inside a polygon without including the boundary?
Is there a way to represent the region inside a polygon without including the boundary? Using RegionBoundary[polygon] includes the boundary.
For example:
points = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
polygon = Polygon[points];
RegionBoundary[polygon]

This includes the boundary of the polygon. However, I want to represent only the interior region, excluding the boundary. How can I achieve that?

reg = RegionDifference[polygon, RegionBoundary@polygon]
{RegionMember[reg, {1, 1/2}], RegionMember[reg, {1/2, 1/2}]}
RegionConvert[reg, "Implicit"]


{False, True}


